# missing argument for parameter in coding error in trying to subclass a uibezierPath

Tags: swift, subclass, draw, uibezierpath, cgrect

I want my swift code to display a uibezierPath button. The code uses   override func draw to draw the button. The code is getting a compile error. Its telling me I am missing a parameter in let customButton = FunkyButton(coder: <#NSCoder#>) you can see the error in NSCODER. I dont know what to put for nscoder. What do you think I should put?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var box = UIImageView()
    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    // Specify the orientation.
    override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscapeRight
    }
    
    let customButton = FunkyButton(coder: <#NSCoder#>)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(box)
        
//        box.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * 0.2, y: view.frame.height * 0.2, width: view.frame.width * 0.2, height: view.frame.height * 0.2)
        
        box.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        customButton!.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        
        
        self.view.addSubview(customButton!)

        customButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(press), for: .touchDown)
    }
    
    @objc func press(){
        print("hit")
    }
    
}

class FunkyButton: UIButton {
  var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
 let aPath = UIBezierPath()
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
       let aPath = UIBezierPath()
        aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.2, y: rect.height * 0.8))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.4, y: rect.height * 0.2))


        //design path in layer
        shapeLayer.path = aPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0

        shapeLayer.path = aPath.cgPath

        // draw is called multiple times so you need to remove the old layer before adding the new one
        shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if self.isHidden == true || self.alpha < 0.1 || self.isUserInteractionEnabled == false {
            return nil
        }
        if aPath.contains(point) {
            return self
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: implement a `override func init(..)` for your FunkyButton and then allocate it with `let customButton = FunkyButton()`.

Comment: i am confused on how to implement that code can you write a answer please.

Comment: @Rob can you provide your instructions as a answer I will give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When instantiating `FunkyButton`, don’t manually call the `coder` rendition. Just call

```
let button = FunkyButton()
```

Or add it in IB and hook up an outlet to

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: FunkyButton!
```

---

In `FunkyButton`, you shouldn't update shape layer path inside `draw(_:)` method. During initialization, just add the shape layer to the layer hierarchy, and whenever you update the shape layer’s path, it will be rendered for you. No `draw(_:)` is needed/desired:

```
@IBDesignable
class FunkyButton: UIButton {
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var path = UIBezierPath()

    // called if button is instantiated programmatically (or as a designable)

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    // called if button is instantiated via IB

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    // called when the button’s frame is set

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePath()
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard path.contains(point) else {
            return nil
        }

        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}

private extension FunkyButton {
    func configure() {
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    func updatePath() {
        path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width * 0.2, y: bounds.height * 0.8))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width * 0.4, y: bounds.height * 0.2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width * 0.2, y: bounds.height * 0.2))
        path.close()
        
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

If you really want to draw your path in `draw(_:)`, that is an acceptable pattern, too, but you wouldn't use `CAShapeLayer` at all, and just manually `stroke()` the `UIBezierPath` in `draw(_:)`. (If you implement this `draw(_:)` method, though, do not use the `rect` parameter of this method, but rather always refer back to the view’s `bounds`.)

Bottom line, either use `draw(_:)` (triggered by calling `setNeedsDisplay`) or use `CAShapeLayer` (and just update its path), but don't do both.

---

A few unrelated observations related to my code snippet:

1. You do not need to check for `!isHidden` or `isUserInteractionEnabled` in `hitTest`, as this method won't be called if the button is hidden or has user interaction disabled. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest) says:

   > This method ignores view objects that are hidden, that have disabled user interactions, or have an alpha level less than 0.01.

   I have also removed the `alpha` check in `hitTest`, as that is non-standard behavior. It is not a big deal, but this is the sort of thing that bites you later on (e.g. change button base class and now it behaves differently).
2. You might as well make it `@IBDesignable` so that you can see it in Interface Builder (IB). There is no harm if you're only using it programmatically, but why not make it capable of being rendered in IB, too?
3. I have moved the configuration of the path into `layoutSubviews`. Anything based upon the `bounds` of the view should be responsive to changes in the layout. Sure, in your example, you are manually setting the `frame`, but this is an unnecessary limitation to place on this button class. You might use auto-layout in the future, and using `layoutSubviews` ensures that it will continue to function as intended. Plus, this way, the path will be updated if the size of the button changes.
4. There's no point in checking for `contains` if the path is a line. So, I've added a third point so that I can test whether the hit point falls within the path.